# how to sum amount from two different tables in one query without using union mysql

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT SUM(amount_paid) AS total_session FROM session 
WHERE session.date = '2016-02-03' AND session.payment_status = 'PAID'
UNION 
SELECT SUM(amount_paid) AS total_subscription FROM subscription 
WHERE subscription.date_enrolled = '2016-02-03'  AND subscription.payment_status = 'PAID'
```

I just want to display the result in two different columns with alias `total_session` and `total_subscription`. How can I do that using union?

Comment: Please don't post a screen shot. Post plain text so we can cut and paste into sqlfiddle. Better yet, make a sqlfiddle for us.

Comment: What's wrong with using `UNION`? What result are you trying to get instead of this?

Comment: You can do it by placing the 2 queries as subqueries in a single query, but it will not be more effective from an execution point of view.

Comment: sorry for the screen shot.. i just want to display the result in two different columns with alias total_session and total_subscription. how can i do that using union?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a UNION, put each query as a subquery in a main `SELECT`

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(amount_paid) FROM session 
    WHERE session.date = '2016-02-03' AND session.payment_status = 'PAID') AS total_paid,
    (SELECT SUM(amount_paid) FROM subscription 
    WHERE subscription.date_enrolled = '2016-02-03'  AND subscription.payment_status = 'PAID') AS total_subscription
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you can try doing a fake join like

```
SELECT xx.total_session, yy.total_subscription
FROM (
SELECT '1' as ID, SUM(amount_paid) AS total_session FROM session 
WHERE session.date = '2016-02-03' AND session.payment_status = 'PAID') xx
JOIN (SELECT '1' as ID, SUM(amount_paid) AS total_subscription FROM subscription 
WHERE subscription.date_enrolled = '2016-02-03'  AND subscription.payment_status = 'PAID') yy
ON xx.ID = yy.ID;
```

Comment: Why do you need the `ID` columns? Just do a `CROSS JOIN` with no `ON` condition.